# But with regard to

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "But with regard to" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> As revealed in Ref. [20], twisted blades affect turbine performance
>   significantly. **But with regard to the twist in the blade profile of
>   Wells turbine**, the blade profile cannot be twisted because the angle
>   of attack will be different in different flow directions and this
>   causes big separation and low performance in one of the flow
>   directions.

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically acceptable: but why do you feel you have to spend so many words saying that you're going to talk about the blade profile in a Wells turbine" before you actually talk about it? Say what you have to say without tiptoeing up to it:

> ... twisted blades affect turbine performance significantly. But in a Wells turbine the blade profile cannot be twisted: the angle of attack will be different in different flow directions, causing separation and low performance in one of the flow directions.